# Regarding the coordinate of the screen?

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I just want to know, isn't the left side coordinate of any UI element is the `Y`, and the top coordinate is the `X`, the bottom coordinates is the `X` and the right coordinates is the `Y`?

is it the correct coordinate system of the screen, because the (0,0) are placed at the top-left corner of the screen? if so, why `oval.set(.., .., .. ..)` does not comply to the coorsinates system that starts from the top-left corner (x,y)? in the documentation of, it is states the following:

`Parameters
left  The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle 
top  The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle 
right  The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle 
bottom  The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle`

Comment: Under any 'normal' co-ordinate system X indicates the horizontal axis and Y the vertical axis. In some cases (a standard graph in maths for example) the co-ordinates (0,0) might be at the bottom left but it's not uncommon in computer graphics to have (0,0) as the top left. This still means (X,Y) refer to (horizontal,vertical) but the X increments from left to right and Y from top to bottom.

Comment: The parameters exactly fit what I described. The value for `left` will be less than `right` and the value for `top` will be less than for `bottom`.

Comment: @Squonk I am totally confused now. if the coor-sys starts from the top-left corner (x=0, y=0) the the `left` is `y` and the `top` is `x`. which completely the converse of the aforementioned parameters in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [View.getLocationOnScreen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) to get your view coordinates

It will return pix offset values relative to **screen's TOP-LEFT point.**

**Note:** getLocationOnScreen() cannot be called before layout buildup is completed.
if in doubt is a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) to be notified when layout is completed.

**Note 2:** The above offsets will change once screen orientation changes (landscape vs. portrait).
If important to your app's processing you might want to declare a listener for that event.
See function [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)